# Continue taking integer input in spite of exception until an empty enter key is pressed

Tags: java, input, exception, exit

I want to find the logic/ code where all the input from the user should be in integer but if integer not given, it will prompt you to enter integer in next turn. Simultaneously add the integer as it comes. Come out of input screen when enter is pressed and print the sum at the end.

Comment: How far have you got? (Show the code)

Comment: you cannot see it?

Comment: No, I cannot see any code.

Comment: Wait, you put it in an answer? I can't tell if you've answered your own question or not. If not, please edit the question and put code in there.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the logic in which a while loop is running and continue till the sc.nextLine() string has length is 0 which means enter-button(key) is being pressed which will lead to exit out of the loop. If input is other than integer, an exception is thrown which is caught in the while loop itself and the loop will continue to take more integer as an input.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ABC {

```
static int sum=0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum=0;
    while(true) 
    {
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        if(s.length()==0)
        {
            break;
        }

        try {
             int number=Integer.parseInt(s);
             sum=sum+number;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Input must be an integer");
            continue;
        }

    }

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

}